# What is the definition of "my ass"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, offensive-language

I have looked at the definition of the phrase *my ass*, and the definition is

> "used to convey that one does not believe something that has just been said"

Could I please get some examples of how the phrase *my ass* is used in a conversation?

Comment: Quite literally...Joe says, "I just won the Nobel Peace Prize!" Bob says, "My ass, you did!"

Comment: See: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/my-foot

Comment: Don't use it. It's incredibly rude.

Comment: Let me give you an example. If someone said "I have a car", but then someone else says "Car, my ass!", would that dialogue make sense?

Comment: ... The implication there is that it is a scooter or donkey rather than a car. 'You have a car, my ass' negates the whole statement.

Comment: Various parts of one's anatomy may be referenced to express disbelief. The sample size is really too small to draw any conclusions, but Google Books has 6 instances of [*Luxury, my **foot**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22luxury+my+foot%22), 5 of *...my **ass**!*, and just 4 of *...my **eye**!* Personally, I'd have thought the relative popularities would be the precise *opposite* of that, but they all sound a bit dated to me anyway. Whatever - it's all just POB, and I agree with @tchrist.

Comment: @GFD1998 Yes, it would.

Answer (score 1):

"My ass"

"My Foot"

"My left nut"

These are all emphatic ways, using a body part, to question the veracity of a speakers claim. The more "offensive the body part, the more emphatic the refutation of the speakers claim.

Refer to the Cambridge Dictionary of American Idiom:

http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/dictionaries/cambridge-dictionary-american-idioms